# Regex to find and replace spaces within pattern

Tags: c#, string, removing-whitespace

I have the following string:

```
"data-template='Test xxx' root{--primary-font:'XYZ Sans';--secondary-font:'Test Sans';--hero-background:#ffbe3f;--header-colour-highlight:#f0591e;--header-background:#ffffff;--header-colour-tabs:#1d2130; }"
```

I need to replace the spaces from `-font:'XYZ Sans'` and `-font:'Test Sans'` in order to make it `-font:'XYZSans'` and `-font:'TestSans'`

Edit: the text inside the `-font:` may change it is not static.

Could anyone help with that?

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: If you expect more than two segments separated by spaces, this will probably be easiest in two passes: one to get the value out of the `-font` variables, and another to replace the blank spaces in it. Otherwise, this should do `sed -E "s/-font:'(\S*)\s+(\S*)';/-font:'\1\2';/g"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

Edit: This also works `(?<=XYZ|Test) (?=Sans)`.

```
(?<=XYZ) (?=Sans)|(?<=Test) (?=Sans)
```

1- `(?<=XYZ)`   `(?=Sans)` match a space preceded by `XYZ` but do not include `XYZ` as a part of that match, at the same time the space should be followed by `Sans`, but don't include `Sans` as a part of the match, we only want the space  . This part will match the first space between `XYZ Sans`

2- `|` the alternation operator `|` , it is like `Boolean OR` If the first part of the regex(i.e., the pattern before `|`) matches a space  , the second part of the regex(i.e., the pattern after `|`) will be ignored, this is not what we want because of that we have to add `g` modifier which means get all matches and don't return after first match. See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/F8r2lG/1). to check the `g` modifier and try to unset it and see the result. it is the `g` right after the regex pattern looks like that `/(?<=XYZ) (?=Sans)|(?<=Test) (?=Sans)/g`  <<

3- `(?<=Test)`   `(?=Sans)` match a space preceded by `Test` but do not include `Test` as a part of that match, at the same time the space should be followed by `Sans`, but don't include `Sans` as a part of the match, we only want the space. This part will match the second space between `Test Sans`

**EDIT:**
This is another regex pattern will match any space exists inside the value of `-font:`, it is dynamic.

```
(?<=-font:\s*['\x22][^'\x22]*?)\s(?=[^'\x22]*)
```

See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/FRiFOM/1).

```
"data-template='Test xxx' root{--primary-font:'XYZ Sans';--secondary-font:'Test Sans';--hero-background:#ffbe3f;--header-colour-highlight:#f0591e;--header-background:#ffffff;--header-colour-tabs:#1d2130; }"
```

**The C# code that does what you want is something like this:**

**Note:** I updated the regex pattern in the code.

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = "\"data-template='Test xxx' root{--primary-font:'XYZ Sans';--secondary-font:'Test Sans';--hero-background:#ffbe3f;--header-colour-highlight:#f0591e;--header-background:#ffffff;--header-colour-tabs:#1d2130; }\"";
      string pattern = @"(?<=-font:\s*['\x22][^'\x22]*?)\s(?=[^'\x22]*)";
      string replacement = "";
      string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
      
      Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
      Console.WriteLine("\n\n-----------------\n\n");
      Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);                             
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention that the values inside the -font: they can change

Comment: I will update the answer with the new regex pattern, thank you !